# How to split multiple spaced numbers in lines -C#

Tags: c#, split, whitespace, delimiter

I want to read each of the columns I underlined in red line by line. The column values as you guys can see are separated by a few spaces. For example, from the first row I only want to read "1" then "MANDIT" then "CLIENT" etc. The problem is that spacing between the values is not constant.

[image]

Here is my code: (There are obvious syntax issues)

```
  StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(Path)
  String line = “ “;
  for (int i =0; i <15; i++)
  {
     line = myReader.readLine();
     string[] delimiters = new string[] { ‘ ’,‘  ’,‘   ’,‘    ’ };
     // Accomodating for different sizes of spaces - is this right?

     int[] columnValues = line.Split(delimiters)
  }
```

Is “stringt [] columnValues = line.Split(delimteres) valid? I have doubles and ints in the data NOT only strings

Thanks guys

Comment: Is this a text file?  Even though you don't have any good delimiter to work with it appears that the columns are all right aligned, is that true?  If so, you could use index of the alignment and then find the first space preceding it to come up with your values.

Comment: What if your 5th column will have value in some rows?

Comment: Is all of the whitespace spaces, or are some tabs or other whitespace characters?

Comment: @TimS. All are white spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking carefully at your image it is clear that you have a file with fixed length columns.
The best approach should be to have an array of lengths and positions for each column desidered.
Then read the line and extract each column using the Substring method.

For example, supposing you are interested in only 4 columns that start at the positions indicated by the `pos` array and have a length indicated by the `len` array

```
int pos[] = new int[] {0, 50, 100, 150};
int len[] = new int[] {3, 40, 20, 15};
....

string[] values = new string[4];
string line;
while((line = myReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   values[0] = line.Substring(pos[0], len[0]);
   values[1] = line.Substring(pos[1], len[1]);
   values[2] = line.Substring(pos[2], len[2]);
   values[3] = line.Substring(pos[3], len[3]);

   .... now convert the values and store or use them ....
}
```

Comment: @L.B you were right, a total different approach is needed. Rewritten the answer.

Comment: Steve, it seems correct now, but ugly. How about looping the `pos`es and creating an array like Split does.

Comment: A `Zip` should let you do that. Or you could declare the things as anonymous types, e.g. `new { pos = 0, len = 3 }` so that the two values are already joined.

Comment: @Steve appreciate the help. What exactly does the position array indicate however ? Is it actual position of my cursor in the line?
Also according to your approach it looks like every single character, rather than whole words ex: "MANDT" will be stored. 
Is there anyway to store whole values rather than breaking them up into individual letters?

Comment: the idea is to use the Substring method that extract from the source string a substring starting from a specified position and taking a specified char length. Your second column could have a 10 character space and starting from position 3, so calling line.Substring(3,10) extract "MANDT....." (dot for spaces because SO use a variable width font).

Comment: @TimS. interesting. Could you elaborate with your own answer? I am very interested in your idea because it is a so common requirement here.

Comment: @Steve I used this code and I get no values in my textbox:

 
               
                string line = myReader.ReadLine();

                int[] pos = new int[15];
                int[] len = new int[100];


                    string[] values = new string[2];
                    
                    while((line != null))
                    {
                        values[0] = line.Substring(pos[4], len[2]);
                        values[1] = line.Substring(pos[6], len[10]);
                  
                   }

                    textBox1.Text = values[1];

Comment: @Steve can I email you my issue? I can't seem to properly paste the code here. Thanks

Comment: I can't promise to have time to look at it, but you could try to upload the project and the file to read in a shared host file service like gdrive, skydrive, dropbox or what else and then post the link here. So other people could look at it also.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be difficult because your fields can have whitespace in them ex: 'Company Code'.  So unless the columns have '\t' tabs between them and your fields can't contain tabs then you probably won't find a good delimiter.

If your third column will never have #s and your 4th will always start with a # then you could read until you reach a number and trim the white space on the ends.

Alternatives:

If you are by chance getting this output from another program you can use C# & powershell to pipe it's output into your program and then the pipe mechanism will handle splitting the columns for you and you will receive a list of objects where each object is the specified line.

Alternatively the file you are looking to read looks like it could be a csv.  Could you have whatever program made that output, instead output it as a csv?  If so then you have your delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and got the advice to solve it this way:

```
StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(Path)
String line = “ “;
for (int i =0; i <15; i++)
{
    line = myReader.ReadLine();
    char[] delimiters = new char[] {' ', '\t'};
    string[] columnValues = line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Split line according to space only.

```
string[] Read = line.Split(' ');
```

You will get an array of string. For each non null or empty item in this string array will be a column value in an order from left to right.

Comment: What about 3rd column? (`FISCAL YEAR`)